# powershell -parallel not working

Tags: powershell, powershell-workflow

I am writing a PowerShell script to display the status of free space and CPU, below is snippet:

```
function Get_FreeSpace ($authType, $comp) {
    $freespace = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
        Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID='E:'" |
            Select-Object Size,Freespace
    } -ComputerName $comp -Credential $authType
    $freesize = [String]::Format("{0:P2}" -f ($freespace.Freespace / $freespace.Size))
    return $freesize
}

function Get_CPUAverage ($authType, $comp) {
    $Cpu_Average = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
        Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor |
            Measure-Object -Property LoadPercentage -Average |
            Select-Object Average
    } -ComputerName $comp -Credential $authType
    return $Cpu_Average.Average
}

workflow Test-Workflow {
    foreach -parallel ($serv1 in $Servers) {
        $Size    = Get_FreeSpace -authType $cred -comp $serv1
        $Cpu_Avg = Get_CPUAverage -authType $cred -comp $serv1
        Write-Host $Size
    }
}

Test-Workflow

Write-Host $Size
```

`$Size` is not returning anything if I use `-parallel` loop.

Comment: `Write-Host` can't be used in workflows like that, and `$Size` inside the workflow is not the same variable as `$Size` outside the workflow. Try removing the assignment operations and the `Write-Host` statement in the `foreach -parallel` loop and collect the workflow output in a variable (`$Size = Test-Workflow`). Also, why are you using a workflow in the first place? Workflows are not PowerShell scripts with some additional features, they're run with a different engine and behave subtly different from regular PowerShell. Don't bother with workflows unless you know what you need them for.

Comment: Thanks for reply,

we have approx. 40 servers and need to execute 10 different commands for each server, it is taking almost 4 mins to complete.

I thought i can fetch the data with foreach -parallel quickly compared to normal foreach loop, is it not correct?

Comment: It may be faster than querying the hosts sequentially, but workflows are comparatively slow. I'd suggest using [background jobs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878288.aspx) for this kind of information gathering.

Answer (score 0):

should pass $Servers as param as shown below:

```
 workflow Test-Workflow {
   param($Servers)
   foreach -parallel ($serv1 in $Servers) {
      $Size    = Get_FreeSpace -authType $cred -comp $serv1
      $Cpu_Avg = Get_CPUAverage -authType $cred -comp $serv1
      Write-Host $Size
   }
 }
```

Test-Workflow $Servers

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, invoke-command runs in parallel with multiple computers:

```
invoke-command comp1,comp2,comp3 { sleep 5; "done $env:computername" }
```